# Argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'slice'

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I am having troubles with deleting slices from a numpy array.

```
x_train[:,:,0]
```

returns the data I want to delete

but

```
np.delete(x_train, np.s_[:,:,0])
```

throws the exception
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'slice'

But in the documentation it is written

> Return a new array with sub-arrays along an axis deleted. For a one dimensional array, this returns those entries not returned by arr[obj].
>
> obj : slice, int or array of ints
>
> Indicate which sub-arrays to remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
arr1 = np.delete(arr1, 0, axis=-1)
```

**Testing it out:**

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.arange(48).reshape(2,3,8)
print (arr1)
arr1 = np.delete(arr1, 0, axis=-1)
print (arr1)
```

**Output:**

```
# Before delete

[[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7]
  [ 8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15]
  [16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23]]

 [[24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31]
  [32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39]
  [40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47]]]

# After delete

[[[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7]
  [ 9 10 11 12 13 14 15]
  [17 18 19 20 21 22 23]]

 [[25 26 27 28 29 30 31]
  [33 34 35 36 37 38 39]
  [41 42 43 44 45 46 47]]]
```

Answer (score 4):

First, in this case, `np.s_` return a tuple, not a slice.
In the documentation, they say you can pass a slice as argument, but in fact they mean the python built in `slice` class ([Doc](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/slice.html))
A valid code would be:

```
x = [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[1,1,1],[2,2,2]],[[5,5,5],[7,7,7]]]
np.delete(x, slice(1,1,1))
```

But let's take a look at the output of `np.s_`.

```
print(np.s_[:,:,0])
```

returns

```
(slice(None,None,None), slice(None,None,None), 0)
```

The output of `np.s_` is a tuple of objets, some are slices and some are indexes, you should read the doc of `np.s_` for more information to know how to use it.
In fact the slice is the object that allow you to write `mylist[0:3]`, in fact this code is just `mylist[slice(0,3)]`
`mylist[:]`, is a special case of slice, in fact `:` is a slice from 0 to `len(mylist)-1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your slice which is not working there. Try

```
np.delete(x_train, np.s_[1,1,1])
```